# windows 8.1 high disk usage

Tags: windows-8.1, acer-aspire

My laptop an Acer Aspire E1-571 has always run on 100% disk usage as far as I can remember, the laptop being about 3 years old. I have just run a disk check with CrystalDiskMark

[image]

I don't really know what these values mean, I can't seem to find a benchmark to compare them to.

When viewing the disk usage in task manager the disk usage is 100% when  3MB/s is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the table mean the following.

First column is related to Read speed from Disk.

First row First column = Sequential data read rate. Meaning, the maximum amount of data that could be read from your disk, which is stored in contigious/continious locations. This value is 68.56 Mbps. It looks like you are on a Hard disk instead of SSD's.

First row Second Column = Sequential Write rate. Meaning, the maximum amount of data that your hard drive could write/store in it. which is 53 MB per second.

When you buy any groceries from store, you get a packet to carry them. The packet/Cover could hold one / two / multiple items depending on its size. 
Similarly when you write any data to a disk, the data needs to be put into a packet and the packet of data is stored. If you are putting too less amount of data in a packet, there is some wastage in the packet, which you are not using.

The 4K represents the packet size. Q32 represents big packets (Say), which you will use for large files like movies or music. etc. 
For regular files, you will use smaller packets. say 4K.

If your packets are spread out unevenly on disk, then when you read the file, the harddisk needs to collect all these randomly placed packets together and should give you. As the packets are randomly placed, it takes more time to pick them up.
This is the Random read and random write speeds.

It takes time to explain all these, but i tried to over simplify it.

As you are using a hard disk with high utilization which is 86% full, there could be a high probability that all your files have been placed unevenly in drive. Try  disk cleanup to remove all unused contents and do a disk defragmentation to rearrange all the packets on your drive. both these should improve performance of the drive.